# `<main>': uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError) using when testing Ruby files

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

I've looked at several posts regarding this issue and I can't seem to find a fix for it. I'm currently working through an assignment in a Ruby on Rails Dev course and we've hit a module on TDD/BDD with RSpec. I've had some success so far but I cannot figure out what to do with this error:

`<main>': uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError)`

I have already gone through my expectations and the code itself line by line to ensure it's correct. RSpec is properly capitalized in the spec file, I have a class with a corresponding `end` which typically cause RSpec to throw this error. I'm still learning RSpec, though. I was working on the last expectation statement when the error started popping up.

**Code**

```
require_relative "entry.rb"

class AddressBook
attr_accessor :entries

  def initialize
   @entries = []
  end

  def add_entry(name, phone, email)
   index = 0
   @entries.each do |entry| 
     if name < entry.name
       break
      end
      index += 1
     end
    @entries.insert(index, Entry.new(name, phone, email))
  end

  def remove_entry

  end
end
```

**RSpec**

```
RSpec.describe AddressBook do  
   context "attributes" do
     it "should respond to entries" do
       book = AddressBook.new
       expect(book).to respond_to(:entries)
     end

     it "should initialize entries as an array" do
       book = AddressBook.new
       expect(book.entries).to be_a(Array)
     end

     it "should initialize entries as empty" do
       book = AddressBook.new
       expect(book.entries.size).eql? 0
     end
   end

   context ".add_entry" do
     it "adds only one entry to the address book" do 
       book = AddressBook.new     
       book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')

        expect(book.entries.size).eql? 1
     end

     it "adds the correct information to entries" do
       book = AddressBook.new     
       book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')
       new_entry = book.entries[0]

       expect(new_entry.name).eql? 'Ada Lovelace'
       expect(new_entry.phone_number).eql? '010.012.1815'
       expect(new_entry.email).eql? 'augusta.king@lovelace.com'
     end
   end
     it "removes only one entry from the address book" do
     book = AddressBook.new

    expect(book.entries.size).to change.by(1)
  end
 end
```

**Update**

I ran rspec spec/address_book_specs.rb as the answer stated below and received the following:

```
/Users/jrshafer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in     `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in     `require'
    from /Users/jrshafer/bloc/code/address-bloc/spec/address_book_specs.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I swear I had absolutely no problems running tests like this before. I've started the project over since I wasn't that far into it and I'm having the same issue.

Comment: What command are you using to run the test?

Comment: from the parent directory: rspec spec/address_book__specs.rb models/address_book.rb

Comment: I've replied as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are coming here as a result of a web search, try this. Insert the first, and then both, of these entries into your /.rspec file:

```
--require spec_helper.rb
--require rails_helper.rb
```

Perhaps it *shakes out* additional info while debugging your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your file with specs should require *spec_helper*, and the file for class you're testing:

```
require "spec_helper"
require_relative "../../lib/address_book" # Please update this accordingly

RSpec.describe AddressBook do  
  context "attributes" do
    it "should respond to entries" do
      book = AddressBook.new
      expect(book).to respond_to(:entries)
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Made the change you suggested and got the following error:


/Users/jrshafer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper.rb (LoadError)
 from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require' from specs/address_book_specs.rb:1:in <main>

Comment: Have you initialized RSpec in your project's directory (with command `rspec --init`)?

Comment: Yes. Running the command again shows both .rspec and spec/spec_helper.rb already exist.

Comment: From error you've provided it looks like, your specs are located in *specs/* instead of *spec/*. Could you move it to directory generated by RSpec?

Comment: I get the same results, with and without the `require "rspec_helper"`

Comment: Actually it should be *spec_helper*, not *rspec_helper* - this is the file generated when initializing rspec

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've been typing and retyping RSpec in various forms for a couple days. -.-

Comment: Which version of RSpec do you use? What is your output of `rspec -v`?

Answer (score 0):

> from the parent directory: rspec spec/address_book__specs.rb models/address_book.rb

You're trying to run two files here, but only one is a test. All you should need is:

`rspec spec/address_book__specs.rb`

Comment: Don't I have to include the file I'm testing?

Comment: Yes. But that is normally done by requiring the file from within the spec, as Paweł shows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help from a local development chat on slack, I was able to find the solution to my issue:

I moved all of my spec files into the spec folder. In `spec/entry_specs` line 2 was changed to `require_relative "../models/entry.rb"`

`models/entry.rb` was empty. Gave it an empty `class Entry; end`. Renamed `entry_specs.rb` to `entry_spec.rb` so I can then just run `rspec` with no arguments to run that spec.

Special thanks to existensil and nickveys at midwestdevchat for helping me on this one. I'm going to order myself some pizza in celebration.